# How to setup Mk livestatus on nagios?

Tags: nagios

I am using `Check_MK` based monitoring on `Nagios`.

```
Check_MK Version: 1.2.0p4
OS: Linux
Nagios Core 3.2.3
```

I want to fetch the `Nagios` page of remote server to local server using `MK Livestatus`.
I am curious, How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nagios Check_mk Multisite (plugin)**

This plugin allow user to view/manage distributed `nagios` using single Web based Interface.

However by default it doesn’t support `pnp4nagios graphs` (hosts/services from remote nagios) access using (single) Multisite URL.

To access `PNP4nagios graphs` of hosts/services from remote `nagios` using `(single) Multisite URL`, we need to Add `Apache Proxy` redirect setting.

**multisite.mk Conf file-**

This is my `“check_mk/multisite.mk”` conf file. (from Primary `multisite` Server (production server), `SITE1` and `SITE2` are two `remote nagios`)

```
OMD[production]:~$ cat etc/check_mk/multisite.mk


…
….
sites = {
#Primary site
“local” : {
“alias” : “PRODUCTION”
},
# Remote site
“SITE1″: {
“alias”: “SITE1″,
“socket”: “tcp:XXX.XXX.X.XX:6557″,
“url_prefix”: “/SITE1/”,
“nagios_url”: “/SITE1/nagios”,
“nagios_cgi_url”: “/SITE1/nagios/cgi-bin”,
“pnp_url”: “/SITE1/pnp4nagios”,
},

# Remote site
“SITE2″: {
“alias”: “SITE2″,
“socket”: “tcp:XXX.XXX.X.XX:6557″,
“url_prefix”: “/SITE2/”,
“nagios_url”: “/SITE2/nagios”,
“nagios_cgi_url”: “/SITE2/nagios/cgi-bin”,
“pnp_url”: “/SITE2/pnp4nagios”,
},
}
….
…..

OMD[production]:~$
```

After making the changes in `multisite.mk` file the `MK Livestatus` of `remote nagios` will be visible at local site.